# CSV File Output Unit Testing Failure

Tags: swift, ios17

I am trying to unit test a function that outputs data to a CSV formatted file. Here is a typical entry generated by my CSV row output module:

**"","January 16, 2024",4:38 PM,,"€535.00",Postbank Bonn,"Bonn,North Rhine-Westphalia Germany"""**

The unusual format of the string is causing the XCTAssertEqual test to fail. To test this string I have to format the comparison string with backslashes as shown below in wdOutput. When it fails I get the message:

XCTAssertEqual failed: (","October 2, 2023",10:30 AM,,"€535.00",Postbank Bonn,"Bonn,North Rhine-Westphalia Germany"
") is not equal to (","October 2, 2023",10:30 AM,,"€535.00",Postbank Bonn,"Bonn,North Rhine-Westphalia Germany"")

As far as I can tell both strings are identical.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.  Thanks

```
  func testWithdrawalCsvRow() throws {
        
        let wdDate = createDate(year: 2023, month: 10, day: 2, hour: 10, minutes: 30)

        let wdCode = "eur"
        let wdBank = "Postbank Bonn"
        let wdAmtL = 500.00
        let wdAmtH = 535.00

        let wdCity = "Bonn"
        let wdState = "North Rhine-Westphalia"
        let wdCountry = "Germany"
        let wdOutput = ",\"October 2, 2023\",10:30 AM,,\"€535.00\",Postbank Bonn,\"Bonn,North Rhine-Westphalia Germany\""
   
        // remove all withdrawal entries
        sut.resetWithdrawals()

        // add a single withdrawal entry
        sut.addNewWithdrawal(wdDate: wdDate, wdCode: wdCode, wdBank: wdBank, wdAmtL: wdAmtL, wdAmtH: wdAmtH, wdLat: PahrumpLt, wdLong: PahrumpLg, wdCity: wdCity, wdState: wdState, wdCountry: wdCountry)
        
        // format our single row to csv
        for item in 0..<sut.wdArray.count {
            sut.messageRow = sut.createTotalRow(item: item, wdCode: wdCode)  // wdCode = currency code of home country
            sut.csvData += sut.messageRow
        }
        
        // does the output match?
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.csvData, wdOutput)
        print(sut.csvData)
```

Comment: There is no SwiftUI here

Comment: Unrelated but it’s a bit weird that you manually update your system-under-test instance inside the unit test. Maybe the issue can be resolved by using a raw string, that is surrounded by a pair of #, so you don’t need to escape anything.

Comment: @Joakim I'm not sure I follow you--I'm not very experienced working with unit testing. What I'm doing is clearing a buffer, adding a single entry, then converting the entry to csv. Finally I check my output for the expected result.

Comment: A raw string is much easier to work with in this case. The input and output match but XCTAssertEqual() fails.  Is there a different test I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much digging around I discovered that my code creating the CSV formatted data has a newline escape sequence (\n) at the end. I added that to the end of the expected result and now the comparison is successful.